# Script to Generate Syntax for Date Range Partitioned Table with 7000 partitions

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

I have to create a range partitioned table with date range for 20 years. Each partition will have data for a single day.

Hence the table will have approx 7,000 partitions ( 20*365 ). Hence manually creating that will be very error prone.

Is there a script which can generate all the partitioning syntax ?

Comment: `partition by (date_col) interval '1' day ( partition pstart values less than(date '2021-01-01') )`. Check [interval partitioning example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)

Comment: I know the syntax. The question is how to generate a script which has storage options, compress options etc (which will be static in my case) but interspersed with over 7,000 partitioning clause

Comment: Why do you want to generate something? Newly created partitions wil inherit their properties from this first partition, where you may provide everything according to [`table_partition_description`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)

Comment: @astentx - bingo !!.  I will simply create table with one partition. And then add new partitions. Of course - I will still have to write a script to generate SQL for 7,000 ADD PARTITIONS but that is much simpler.

Comment: Why do you think you need to manually add the partitions though? They will be created automatically as data is inserted?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I have to load historical data into table for 20 years. Due to performance requirements the table will need to be partitioned for each day. Hence we will end with a table with 7,000 partitions ( 20*365 ).

Comment: Did you check the documentation about interval partitioning? Looks like we are discussing different things. Correction: newly generated partitions will inherit storage attributes etc from the table definition, not sure about the first partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code from a partition maintenance routine I wrote a while back... It should get you started. I used to schedule it nightly to look for intervals and clean them up

```
declare
  l_high_value         varchar2(4000);
  l_partition_boundary date;
  l_parname            varchar2(40);
  l_ddl                varchar2(4000);
begin
    for i in ( 
      select a.owner, a.table_name, a.partitioning_type, t.partition_name, t.high_value, a.interval
      from   all_part_tables a, all_tab_partitions t
      where  a.owner = ...
      and    a.partitioning_type = 'RANGE'
      and    a.table_name not like 'BIN$%'
      and    a.interval is not null
      and    t.table_owner = a.owner
      and    t.table_name  = a.table_name
      and    regexp_like(t.partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}') ) 
    loop  
      begin
        l_high_value := i.high_value;
        execute immediate 'select '||l_high_value||'-1 from dual' into l_partition_boundary;

        if upper(i.interval) like 'NUMTODSINTERVAL%' then
           l_parname := substr(i.table_name,1,21)||'_'||to_char(l_partition_boundary,'YYYYMMDD');
        elsif upper(i.interval) like 'NUMTOYMINTERVAL%MONTH%' then
           l_parname := substr(i.table_name,1,23)||'_'||to_char(l_partition_boundary,'YYYYMM');
        elsif upper(i.interval) like 'NUMTOYMINTERVAL%YEAR%' then
           l_parname := substr(i.table_name,1,25)||'_'||to_char(l_partition_boundary,'YYYY');
        elsif upper(i.interval) like 'INTERVAL''%''DAY%' then
           l_parname := substr(i.table_name,1,21)||'_'||to_char(l_partition_boundary,'YYYYMMDD');
        elsif upper(i.interval) like 'INTERVAL''%''MONTH%' then
           l_parname := substr(i.table_name,1,23)||'_'||to_char(l_partition_boundary,'YYYYMM');
        elsif upper(i.interval) like 'INTERVAL''%''YEAR%' then
           l_parname := substr(i.table_name,1,25)||'_'||to_char(l_partition_boundary,'YYYY');
        else
           l_parname := null;
           dbms_output.put_line ('Cannot determine correct partition name for table ' || i.table_name || ' partition ' || i.partition_name); 
        end if;
      exception
        when others then
           l_parname := null;
           dbms_output.put_line ('Cannot determine correct partition name for table ' || i.table_name || ' partition ' || i.partition_name||' hi='||l_high_value); 
      end;

      if (l_parname is not null) then
        l_ddl := 'alter table '||i.owner||'.'||i.table_name||' rename partition '||i.partition_name||' to '||l_parname;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_ddl);

        begin
          execute immediate l_ddl;
        exception
          when others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Failed with '||sqlerrm);
        end;

      end if;
    end loop;

    --
    -- then we can use those new partition names to do the same for indexes
    --

    for i in ( 
            with tabpar as ( 
             select /*+ materialize */ 
                     a.owner, a.table_name, a.partitioning_type, t.partition_name, t.partition_position
              from   all_part_tables a, all_tab_partitions t
              where  a.owner = ...
              and    a.partitioning_type = 'RANGE'
              and    a.table_name not like 'BIN$%'
              and    a.interval is not null
              and    t.table_owner = a.owner
              and    t.table_name  = a.table_name
            ), indpar as (
             select /*+ materialize */ 
                     ai.owner, ai.table_name, ai.index_name, i.partition_name, i.partition_position
              from   all_part_indexes ai, all_ind_partitions i
              where  ai.owner = ...
              and    ai.partitioning_type = 'RANGE'
              and    ai.table_name not like 'BIN$%'
              and    ai.interval is not null
              and    i.index_owner = ai.owner
              and    ai.index_name  = i.index_name
              and    ai.locality = 'LOCAL'
            )
            select t.owner, t.table_name, t.partition_name new_par_name, i.index_name, i.partition_name
                  from   tabpar t, indpar i
                  where  i.owner = t.owner
                  and    i.table_name = t.table_name
                  and    i.partition_position = t.partition_position
                  and    not regexp_like(t.partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')
                  and    regexp_like(i.partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')   
    )
    loop  
      l_ddl := 'alter index '||i.owner||'.'||i.index_name||' rename partition '||i.partition_name||' to '||i.new_par_name;
      dbms_output.put_line(l_ddl);
      begin
        execute immediate l_ddl;
      exception
        when others then
          dbms_output.put_line('Failed with '||sqlerrm);
      end;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: @oradbanj did my rename PARTITION code work out for you? If so can you accept my solution

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

partition by range (date_col)
interval (numtoyminterval(1, 'DAY'))
(partition P_OLDDATA
values less than
(to_date('01-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'))
);
The statement creates a table with:

anchor partition of < 01-Jan-2021: This means that any data older than 01-Jan-2021 will go into partition P_OLDDATA.
interval of 1 day: This means that any data dated01-Jan-2021 or later will go into its own day partition. If such a partition does not exist already, Oracle will create it automatically.

In summary, your historical data will be in 1 partition and your new data will be partitioned daily in its own partition.

Comment: this is excellent. I created table with 1 partition. Then wrote a script to add data for other dates. It automatically created other partitions. The only thing is that it names the partitions as SYS_12345 etc. Now I have to figure out a way to name them intuitively

Comment: Why would you care what the names of the partitons are as they should be referenced by value(in your case date) and not name, which would be a mistake. Why would you need a script to add other dates as Oracle automatically generates the PARTITION when a new date is added

Comment: The problem is that some developers are using partition names in their queries ( example : SELECT * from table partition X )

Comment: Try this https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-rename-interval-partition-with-more-meaningful-name/

Answer (score 0):

Relying on a name is poor coding and your application should be fixed.

Instead of using a partition name to find the amount of rows per day you can use a simple query.

Substitute the correct variable name for create_date.

```
select trunc(created_date), count(*) as num_created
from the_table
group by trunc(created_date);
```

The trunc() is necessary because in Oracle a DATE column contains a time part as well (or if your created_date is in fact a timestamp not a date).

Answer (score 0):

Someone in my company had the same concerns about the automotic PARTITION names so we now use this procedure.

You can run it manually or set up a scheduled task to run it automatically. I would suggest the later.

If you like the answer please upvote it and accept.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MaintainPartitions IS  EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE, -6550);

    CURSOR PartTables IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, INTERVAL
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    WHERE PARTITIONING_TYPE = 'RANGE' 
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

    CURSOR TabParts(aTableName VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE regexp_like(partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')  AND
 TABLE_NAME = aTableName AND
table_name not like 'BIN$%'
      and    interval is not null
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

    ym INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    newPartName VARCHAR2(30);
    PERIOD TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

    FOR aTab IN PartTables LOOP 
        BEGIN       
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ds;
            ym := NULL; 
        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ym;
                ds := NULL;         
        END;            

        FOR aPart IN TabParts(aTab.TABLE_NAME) LOOP         
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT PERIOD;
            IF ds IS NOT NULL THEN
                IF ds >= INTERVAL '7' DAY THEN
                    -- Weekly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"IYYY"W"IW';
                ELSE
                    -- Daily partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMMDD';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                IF ym = INTERVAL '3' MONTH THEN
                    -- Quarterly partition 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYY"Q"Q';
                ELSE
                    -- Monthly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMM';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            IF newPartName <> aPart.PARTITION_NAME THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' RENAME PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' TO '||newPartName;
            END IF;             
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END MaintainPartitions;

EXEC MaintainPartitions
```